# ¿Cómo crear un fondo y barra superior transparente JFrame?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando crear un fondo/barra superior transparente, encontré este ejemplo:

```
public texscroll() {
    initComponents();
    setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
}
```

Pero este no funciona, no ejecuta la aplicación al agregar ese código, generándose el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: marquesinajava.texscroll.initComponents
    at marquesinajava.texscroll.<init>(texscroll.java:30)
    at marquesinajava.Textmovie.main(Textmovie.java:28)
Java Result: 1
```

Mi idea es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la documentación de [oracle encontré algunos ejemplos ejecutables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) el segundo ejemplo es el ideal, lo que deseo lograr al ejecutar la aplicación, descargue los ejecutables de muestra y es perfecto, pero no comprendo muy bien la documentación de los ejemplos.

Este es mi código

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 *
 * @author inide
 */
public class Textmovie {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame jf = new JFrame("FGHJK");
       jf.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
       jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       jf.add(new texscroll());
       jf.setSize(720,480);

       jf.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Podrían explicarme cual debe ser las configuraciones o que linea modificar para lograr que el fondo/barra sean trasparente como se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: Cuando dices "no funciona" ¿A qué te refieres? ¿Algún mensaje de error? ¿O solo que no hace nada?

Comment: Y... ¿has probado a ver qué te devuelve `isWindowTranslucencySupported`?

Comment: @SJuan76 He editado mi pregunta pasteando el error que se muestra, se muestra el error y la aplicación no se ejecuta.

Comment: Parece un bug de netbeans; una búsqueda del error da esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114025/uncompilable-source-code-erroneous-sym-type

Comment: @SJuan76 Más allá del problema que causa, existe incompatibilidad, el código no parece ser apto para el código que se está ejecutando, probando línea por línea igual genera los mismos errores, ejemplo probado `jf.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));` así que la solución enlazada no resuelve el problema ni tampoco lograra lo que desea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de la JDK7 introdujeron a `setOpacity()` de cara a sacar en un futuro el uso de `AWTUtilities`, mas específicamente `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque()`.

Para lograr el efecto translucido con `setOpacity()`, son necesarias 3 condiciones:

> 1. Las transparencias deben ser soportadas por el sistema.
> 2. La ventana debe estar sin decorar (`setUndecorated(true)`).
> 3. La ventana NO puede estar en modo *pantalla completa* (`GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(w)`).

[setOpacity() documentación JDK7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setOpacity%28float%29)

En ese orden de ideas, al código que proporcionaste podrías hacerle un par de ajustes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Frame jf = new JFrame();
  jf.setUndecorated(true);//Decoraciones Deshabilitadas
  jf.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,10));//Transparencia
  //...
}
```

---

```
public class texsrcoll extends JPanel {
  int x=510, y=25;
  public texscroll() {
    setOpaque(false);//Deshabilita color de fondo del JPanel
  }
  //..
}
```

Como resultado puede obtenerse el `JFrame` con transparencia y, en este caso con texto desplazándose de derecha a izquierda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es exactamente el mismo código fuente, sin importar otras clases y claro, salvo las modificaciones posteadas en la respuesta; no usé Netbeans, que entre otras cosas hay comentarios acerca de un bug en ese IDE.